# ScrollViewer display two scroll

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to create a simple log visualizer, so I did the following:

```
<ScrollViewer>
            <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" Height="240" IsReadOnly="True"
                     ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                     ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                     />
 </ScrollViewer>
```

the ScrollViewer is inside a GroupBox, I can manage it correctly behind the code, but the problem's that I've this UI result:

[image]

Howyou can see I've an internal scroller (that working) and an external scroller, that is the ScrollViewer.

This is very strange, wpf doesn't take only one scroller automatically? How can I hide the external scroller, or anyway, display just one scroller for the control?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just skip the <ScrollViewer>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

both scrolls are visible if there is too much `Text` for a fixed `Height`

try set Height for ScrollViewer

```
<ScrollViewer Height="240">
<TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" IsReadOnly="True"
         HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
         VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
         ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

or remove ScrollViewer completely

```
<TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" Height="240" IsReadOnly="True"
         HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
         VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
         ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using a `ScrollViewer` on the outside of a multiline `TextBox`. The `ScrollViewer` is meant to contain a bunch of UI elements that would otherwise take up a bunch of space. The best comparison I can make is a webpage. The browser acts as a ScrollViewer, and the webpage is the contents.

If you are only needing the `TextBox`, you don't need the `ScrollViewer`. But, if you do want to use the `ScrollViewer`, this will get rid of the scrollbar when not needed:

```
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" CanContentScroll="True">
            <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" Height="240" IsReadOnly="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
        </ScrollViewer>
```